# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written following program for my project purpose.

```
import glob
import os
path = "/home/madhusudan/1/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path)

s1 = "<add>\n<doc>\n\t<field name = \"id\">"
s2 = "</field>\n"
s3 = "<field name = \"features\">"
s4 = "</doc>\n</add>"

i = 150
for file in files:
    f = open(file,"r")
    str = f.read()
    file1 = "/home/madhusudan/2/"+os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] + ".xml"
    f1 = open(file1,"w")
    content = s1 + str(i) + s2 + s3 + f.read() + s2 + s4 
    f1.write(content)
    i = i + 1
```

While running this code I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    id1 = str(i)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the code you posted; we can see a *similar line* that has the same problem, but do post actual errors thrown by the code you posted.

Comment: Use different variable instead of `str`.

Comment: `str = f.read()` shows that you are obviously not interested in keeping access to the builtin `str` function/type. That's ok, but you should be aware that you should stand by that. (SCNR)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You assigned the file contents to `str`:

```
str = f.read()
```

This masks the built-in function.

Don't use `str` as a local name; pick something else.

Answer (score 3):

In the following line, the code overwrite builtin function `str` with a string object.

```
str = f.read()
```

Use different name to prevent that.

---

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str = 'string object'
>>> str(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a reserved name to handle string values .
so you can use it as a local variable name.
pick something else.
do

```
str_value = f.read()
```